# Present perfect's precise meaning?

Tags: present-perfect

> M's use of the exemption.221 In funding its production company, Legion M had already raised over $400,000 from accredited investors before opening up the offering to the general public.222 Legion M then raised the permitted $1 million from over 3,000 investors and **became** the first " fan-owned entertainment company. " 223 The media grabbed onto Legion M's story, and it has received a notable amount of good press and notoriety.224 Further, once Legion M begins producing movies, it will have an army of investors with a stake in each film's success that will undoubtedly function as a kind of grassroots marketing team. Essentially, the cost of SEC compliance **becomes** an investment for companies or filmmakers like Legion M, who can leverage their use of the equity crowdfunding exemption

When i use present perfect **has become** instead of both **became** and **becomes,** what is the difference?
To me, there seems no difference.

I edited the question  with the sentences in the context to narrow down my confusion

Comment: The problem is that the precise difference depends on the verb, and the context. Trying to make a general rule is just going to lead to an ever-growing list of exceptions.

Comment: As SamBC suggests, the meaning of a perfect is dependent on context. You may find this helpful: [*What is the perfect, and how should I use it?*](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/13255/32), especially §§ [3.1 Grammatical meaning](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/13260/32) and [3.2 Pragmatic meaning](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/13261/32).

Answer (score 1):

1) X has become the first [whatever]

A) This locates the action as originating in the past without specifying when this happened. For example, specific would be: last  year, last month, ten years ago.

B) This also means that whatever the outcome is continues at the time of speaking

Another example: He has become rich.

Implication: at the time of speaking now in the present he is **still rich** and we don't know specifically **when in the past he became rich.**

2) X became [whatever]

- This locates the outcome at a specific time or moment  in the past.

Another example: He became rich **last year.**

"He has become rich last year." would be wrong.

Unless the entire text uses  historical present (using the present tense to tell a story about the past), **becomes** would not be right here.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the first bolded word, *became*, *has become*, then you are decoupling the raising of money from the becoming. The use of the two past simple (preterite) verb phrases coupled with *and* implies a connection between the two verbs phrases, generally a causal connection - the first in some way caused the second, or the two have common cause. The same is true if you have two coupled simple presents, or a preterite and a simple present, and I'm pretty sure it applies with progressives as well. It can happen with a present perfect followed by a present simple, or a past perfect followed by a preterite or present perfect.

It doesn't work with a preterite followed by a present perfect. It just makes it look like you are stating two things that are not related. The implication in the text as it stands is that the two are closely related, that it is the raising of money that either *defined* becoming "fan-owned", or that becoming fan-owned was a consequence of raising the money.

In the second case, we currently have a use of the present simple to make a general statement. Use of the present perfect changes that to talk about something that has happened. The change in meaning is subtle, but in this case I would say that the use of the perfect was wrong because the hypothesised benefit has not actually borne fruit yet.